# Timing issue with Django signals and login redirect

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, signals

Consider this simple login view:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get('bounce', '/')

        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=self.request.get_host()):
            redirect_to = '/'

        user = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
        )
        login(self.request, user)

        return redirect(redirect_to)
```

After logging in via `/login/?bounce=/something`, I'm redirected back to `/login/?bounce=/something`, as if I never logged in. After some investigating, if I launch an IPython session right after `login()` and exit it in a second or two, the login view works correctly.

Looking at the source code of `login`, this function actually uses signals to log the user in:

```
user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
```

I've run into similar timing issues with signals. How do I avoid this? I'm using my own `LoginView`, but the same problem existed with the default Django one.

If I add a check in the main `get` method of the view, I can waste a few redirects and eventually log the user in, but it seems like a huge hack:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            redirect_to = self.request.GET.get('bounce', '/')

            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=self.request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = '/'

            return redirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            return super(LoginView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get('bounce', '/')

        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=self.request.get_host()):
            redirect_to = '/'

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
            )
            login(self.request, user)

        return redirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: confused - you will always be redirected, cos you have a redirect. The user has been logged in it seems, cos thats what login() will do, then you redirect. Are you saying the user is still anon? Also - i presume you have a reason for not using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings?

Comment: @professorDante: I get redirected back to the login page, which redirects me again to the login page, and so on. After 1 to 3 times, I get sent off to the right page.

Comment: @professorDante: As for `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, I don't like keeping my URL routing spread out between 5 files. It makes no difference.